# Ubuntu Nvidia drivers vs Nvidia drivers from the website

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu, gpu-driver

What is the difference? 
I can see that the 'Additional drivers' section installed drivers that are older than the latest ones available on the website.

Are there any drawback to installing Nvidia drivers straight from the website with the `.run` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE 24/11/2016

Now you can use the most up-to-date nvidia driver without much worries thanks to the launchpad's Proprietary GPU Drivers PPA (note that this ppa is still considered in testing)

You just need to add the ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
```

and install your nvidia-(version) driver using the 'additional drivers'  ubuntu software. I suggest you to read more here: [Link](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in.html)

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

The Ubuntu nvidia drivers are drivers that have been tested by the Ubuntu team and so they guarantee that this drivers will work with ubuntu without breaking anything, so because they have to test the drivers and ensure that everything works as expected they get behind the nvidia most up to date releases.

You can try with the Nvidia website drivers but this is risky, you have to know what you are doing and how to solve any problem.

So this is a trade off, you choose.